# Seperating dev and prod with android and firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I recently deployed an app to the play store and i am using firebase as backend. However, now I want to add some features to the app and want to create different environments so that i can test the app in a similar environment before releasing to production.

I went through these links online but I have some doubts.

1. https://medium.com/@Miqubel/multiple-build-types-in-firebase-on-android-6f6715f6dd83
2. https://web.archive.org/web/20160310115701/https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-29-managing-development-environments.html

The app currently in PROD has database, functions and storage configured. So my goal is to have a mirror image of this setup through which i would test my app without affecting anything in the PROD database setup.

**So far what i have figured out is:**

1: I need to have different build types in my build gradle.

2: Somehow make my different build for DEV and PROD point to different databases on firebase.

**Confusion:**

Should I create two different projects on firebase or have two apps in 1 project?

When we have two apps in one firebase project does it have separate database or a single shared database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's recommended to have different projects for each environment that you want to test separately.  Don't use the same project for development and production, because your changes during development could cause problems in production.

Please read [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) for more information.